# Show code / element if custom field is present

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, if-statement, custom-fields

basically I'm looking for the simplest code possible to solve this issue. I have an iframe that is populated when a custom field is populated for the iframe src.

Basically, I want the iframe code to disappear completely if the custom field isn't filled in.

This is so I can pop this code in the page.php and the iframe only shows if the custom field is populated.

```
<?php
    $iframe_src = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'iframe_src', true );
    $iframe_height = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'iframe_height', true );

    $height = ( $iframe_height == "" || !$iframe_height ) ? 2650 : $iframe_height;
?>
<iframe SRC="<?php echo $iframe_src; ?>" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="<?php echo $height; ?>" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="content"></iframe>
```

Comment: `if ($iframe_src != '') { ... }` ?

Comment: Sorry I'm rather new, where do I put this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if `$iframe_src` is set like:

```
<?php 
   if(!empty($iframe_src)) {
       ?><iframe SRC="<?php echo $iframe_src; ?>" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="<?php echo $height; ?>" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="content"></iframe><?php
   }
?>
```

Comment: Not working unfortunately, nothing's showing up. This page has the iframe SRC populated but it's not working on the page: http://projectprintsolutions.pps.staging.wpengine.com/print-products/3d-merchandisers/

Comment: I guess it hasn't, otherwise your iframe wouldn't have a source.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try `echo $iframe_src;` and see if you get anything.